# Retrieve a value from Database and set it as @Table Name value in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I have a Class with **@Table** annotation, currently I directly set the Name value like this :

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "US_STUDENTS" )
public class Student {

// some properties

}
```

I have a table in DB named **MasterCountries** which have a **Column name** - **value** =
**countryPrefix** - **"US_"**

When the Spring boot app run, I want to take this data from the DB and use it as part of the @Table name value to make it like this :

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = countryPrefix + "STUDENTS" ) // so the end result will be "US_STUDENTS"
public class Student {

// some properties

}
```

I've google'd and still have not found a solution to this, the reason is because I want to make it dynamic, whenever this spring boot service need to be redeployed for other country, just need to retrieve the specific countryPrefix from the DB, so no need to change the code again for each country Deployment.

for the **repository** I set up an interface that extends JpaRepository as shown below :

```
public interface MasterCountriesRepository extends JpaRepository<CountriesSetting, Long> {

    CountriesSetting findByCountryCode(String countryCode);

}
```

and for the **CountriesSetting** entity :

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "MasterCountries" )
public class CountriesSetting {

// some properties

}
```

Is this possible to achieve in spring JPA ?
please ignore any mistype or minor syntax problem, as this is not the real code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't nor has this anything to do with Spring or Spring Data JPA, but how plain JPA works. You might be able to shoehorn a HIbernate namingstrategy into this (for this specific table) but you would need to use plain SQL and not JPA. Because JPA needs to be fully available before you can use it to query, however to be able to build the metadata it needs data from the same database (you basically have a chicken and egg problem here).

Comment: I wonder whether using multiple datasource (a first one to only work with country settings) and one per country (instantiated programmatically) would work.
You would instantiate a map of datasource based on the country.
But I think you have a design issue, you might simply need partitioning (wording differs based on DBMS).

Comment: As I know in JPA you need to know beforehand at what table an entity refer to.  If you just need to READ data you may consider to create a DB view with a union of different tables with the country as an additional field and create an entity that refers to it. If it is not applicable you may consider jdbcTemplate instead of JPA or in the worst case @autowire directly the Datasource object and write queries manually,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations **require** that everything involved in their usage is a compile time constant. That's by java spec, you can't ask the compiler to forget about that restriction just for a moment.

Any expression is a 'compile time constant' if it is:

- A literal... but `null` doesn't count!
- Of the form `X ! Y` where X and Y are 'compile time constant', and `!` is some operator, such as + or -.
- A reference to a field which is [A] static, [B] final, [C] whose type is `String` or primitive, [D] whose initializing expression is 'compile time constant' (using this same definition, recursively).

Thus, `Foo.x` is compile time constant given:

```
class Foo {
   static final int x = 5 - 3 + Integer.MAX_VALUE - Bar.y;
}
class Bar {
   static final int y = 10;
}
```

but these aren't:

- `static final long z = System.currentTimeMillis();`
- `static final String y = null;`
- `static final String a = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1).toString();`

Note that the third seems constant (the output of that expression is set in stone and will be the same on all VMs, forever), and yet doesn't count, as it isn't explicitly named in the java lang spec.

Given that you want to retrieve this from the database, what you want is **impossible** - as surely your intent is that the table name is *not* locked in during compilation, and yet the reason why the expression you feed to an annotation param must be compile time constant is that the compiler **must** lock it in.

### So what is the solution?

Don't use the annotations. Annotations that are queried at runtime are usually a configuration shortcut. Generally there is a more roundabout way to achieve the same goal, calling APIs which default to 'I shall just read out the annotation value'.

Annotations can also be queried at compile time - lombok does that, as do Annotation Processors (e.g. processors that produce XML-based config files during your compilation run). Trivially it should be obvious to you that your entire plan cannot possibly work then - these are fundamentally 'at compile time' concepts.

### Simpler suggestion

Thinking out of the box, perhaps:

Have a separate script that will run a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement that creates a view with a singular name (just `Students` for example), that just mirrors a stated table (Such as `US_Students`), using `ON INSERT` and `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` to also 'pass through' any attempt to insert/update/delete attempts on this view to end up affecting the `US_Students` table.

To 'change' the 'country', just run that script one-off and restart the java app, and voila.

How to make views and have them work with delete/insert/update depends on your DB engine. In both MySQL and postgres, a basic view on a simple `SELECT` without aggregates and joins and such 'just works'.

You're really just looking at:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Students AS SELECT * FROM US_Students;
```

run that single statement and you're good to go.

Comment: using entityManager's createQuery / createNativeQuery seems a more fit for this requirements instead a JpaRepository and @Table annotation, I'll try this.
But Thank you for the explanation, it helped me understand some of the things that happened under the hood in spring-data-jpa.